# Pandas changing the first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello, [as you see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXYSu.png) i have a csv file. The problem is first column (leftmost) does not begin with 1 but it is like the column "gene". How can i fix it?
I want that starts with 1 and go to end of the list.

Comment: That is index column not a regular column

Answer (score 1):

Did you do this?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', index_col='Gene')
```

Just remove index_col and it should, by default, create a new index column.